# How to check processes created within a specific time using powershell, even if they already exited?

Tags: powershell

I am using...

```
get-process -name * |
where-object {$_.StartTime -ge "5/1/2017" -and $_.StartTime -le "5/2/2017"} |
export-csv -path c:\processes_created.csv
```

However, it fails to capture processes that have already exited.

Comment: Windows does not retain a list of processes that have been created/destroyed. That information simply is not available. If you need that, I'd advise you to use *sysmon* from SysInternals *(Microsoft)* and search the eventlog.

Comment: If that's true, then what I am seeing are merely processes that are currently running. Sysmon/procmon is not applicable because I don't intend to monitor a process. Anyway, thanks. I'll try to look for alternative forensic tools/methods.

Comment: You could take a look at [Windows Prefetch](http://www.forensicswiki.org/wiki/Windows_Prefetch_File_Format) to get *some* information like runcount and last runtime about processes. Note that prefetch can be disabled/cleaned so if you need this for forensics keep in mind that absence of evidence is no evidence of absence.

Comment: You should probably devise an agent that will monitor process start events and record that.

Comment: @Vesper - it would be hard to beat sysmon's performance and reliability using a home brew solution. It might make a good learning experience.

Comment: @LievenKeersmaekers Then OP has to configure process auditing and parse security logs for process start events, or rely on sysmon/procmon, or maybe on another tool that can sniff process start events and log them.

Comment: @Vesper - lol. I didn't even think of auditing, tx.

Comment: @Lieven Keersmaekers - That's it. Checking prefetch might work.